CI/CD Process - Xcode Apple Session Expires
I've got a new Mac build server for deploying my apps.  But on this Mac for some reason, the Apple ID account doesn't stay logged in and the session expires.  So every time, before I build, I need to log onto the server and refresh the Apple ID session in Xcode otherwise the upload to apple part of my CI/CD pipeline fails.
I'm using the standard XCODEBUILD cli for build and deployment.
This doesn't happen on my development Mac or any other Mac that I've owned.
I would love some guidance on where to look or what to change to prevent the session from expiring.
TIA
Steve H
